# How to display input errors in popup?

Tags: android, validation, popup, android-edittext

I want to show all my validation error's of `EdiText` fields in a popup as shown in below image:

[image: Error alert in popup]

As far as I know Android has drawables:

> 1) popup_inline_error.9.png

[image: popup_inline_error.9.png]

> 2) popup_inline_error_above.9.png

[image: popup_inline_error_above.9]

> 3) indicator_input_error.png

[image: indicator_input_error.png]

I am able to display the red error indicator inside the right side of the `EditText` by using:

```
Drawable err_indiactor = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.indicator_input_error);
mEdiText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, err_indiactor, null);
```

Now also i want to display the error message as shown is the first image but it seems I am not getting any idea about this, though I think it should be a Custom Toast.

Comment: +1 for great question

Comment: Can we use frame layout above the editbox and initially set the visibility to gone then visible.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try this..

```
final EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

 editText.setImeActionLabel("",EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);

        editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){
                    if( editText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        editText.setError("Please enter some thing!!!");
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Notnull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: **+1** @SBK: Thanks for this. It seems simple task and I was doing a lot of research on this, though it was very interesting.

Comment: rather than using the IME_ACTION_NEXT to trigger a validation I prefer to setOnFocusChangeListener with if (!hasFocus) && field.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) field.setError("Please enter some thing!!!");
Otherwise the validation code is not executed when the user taps into the next TextEdit.

Comment: In RTL layout I tried this code but only the icon is showing and the error popup message not shown!!! why???

Answer (score 38):

As the earlier answer is solution for my problem but I have tried a different approach to use a custom Drawable image instead of default `indicator_input_error` image.

### Default Drawable

[image: Default Drawable]

### Custom Drawable

[image: Custom Drawable]

So, I have just created two `EditText` in my layout xml file and then implemented some `Listener` in Java code on that `EditText`.

### main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:padding="20dip"
    android:background="#222222">
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Username"
        android:id="@+id/etUsername" android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeActionLabel="Next"></EditText>
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Password"
        android:id="@+id/etPassword" android:singleLine="true"
        android:imeActionLabel="Next"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

### EditTextValidator.java

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;

public class EditTextValidator extends Activity {

    private EditText mUsername, mPassword;

    private Drawable error_indicator;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Setting custom drawable instead of red error indicator,
        error_indicator = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.emo_im_yelling);

        int left = 0;
        int top = 0;

        int right = error_indicator.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int bottom = error_indicator.getIntrinsicWidth();

        error_indicator.setBounds(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom));

        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        // Called when user type in EditText
        mUsername.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mUsername));
        mPassword.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(mPassword));

        // Called when an action is performed on the EditText
        mUsername.setOnEditorActionListener(new EmptyTextListener(mUsername));
        mPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new EmptyTextListener(mPassword));
    }

    private class InputValidator implements TextWatcher {
        private EditText et;

        private InputValidator(EditText editText) {
            this.et = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (s.length() != 0) {
                switch (et.getId()) {
                case R.id.etUsername: {
                    if (!Pattern.matches("^[a-z]{1,16}$", s)) {
                        et.setError("Oops! Username must have only a-z");
                    }
                }
                    break;

                case R.id.etPassword: {
                    if (!Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]{1,16}$", s)) {
                        et.setError("Oops! Password must have only a-z and A-Z");
                    }
                }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class EmptyTextListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
        private EditText et;

        public EmptyTextListener(EditText editText) {
            this.et = editText;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                // Called when user press Next button on the soft keyboard

                if (et.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    et.setError("Oops! empty.", error_indicator);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have tested it like:

> For empty EditText validations :

Suppose user click on the `Username` field then Softkeybord opens and if user press `Next` key then the user will be focused to the `Password` field and `Username` field remains empty then the error will be shown like as given in below images:

[image: Empty text]
[image: Empty text]

> For wrong input validations :

1) I type the text `vikaS` in Username field then error will be like as given in below image :

[image: Wrong username]

2) I type the text `Password1` in password field then error will be like as given in below image :

[image: wrong password]

### Note:

Here I have used custom drawable only in case of when user left the EditText field blank and press Next key on key board but you can use it in any case. Only you need to supply `Drawable` object in `setError()` method.

Comment: @Vikas : Thanks for wonderful answer. How did you set the outer red dialog box?

Comment: @vikas can you tell me what if i need to change that red color to green color..?

Comment: @perfection It has been long time since I worked on but I think if you need to change only color of the text then you can use html formatted text but if you want whole tooltip then you can make some 9 patch png images of desired color and use a custom views to show error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I know answer has been accepted by the asker, but none of the above worked for me.

I was able to reproduce this on my Nexus S running Android 4.0.3.

Here's how I made it work.

1. Create a theme with:

   ```
   <style name="MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/primary_text_light
        </item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Apply `MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` theme to my application / activity  from manifest.

   ```
       <application
            android:name=".MyApp"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/MyApp.Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
       >
   ```

Comment: **+1** I have no information about the new API's, as I have been no longer working for this platform but If you really want to know in more detail then I would recommend you to check my answer. Thanks :)