# Custom validation in Android

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display input validation errors in popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218691/display-input-validation-errors-in-popup)

[image]

Please look the given above image i want to put Validation like this in edittext.
I have use setError but it not look like this i am not understand how to customize these property. Please give me any suggestion about getting solution.

Comment: No it is not a duplicate question i have already see it before posting this question because in that question a error message is show right side but i want to show it on left side how can it possible.

Comment: It is a duplicate.  If you want to show it on the left side instead of the right side, then ask your question that way, assuming you already know how to create the Toast.

Comment: Dear Robert please see carefully the above picture it is not a Toast it is a custom validation i have got it in an application name is Evernote if you want to see it click on this link and https://market.android.com/details?id=com.evernote&feature=search_result and install on your device then click on create account link of this application on the front page. Then you got it i am right and it is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create some custom notifications you'll have to show a Toast with a custom layout.

Comment: Thanks for replay. We are able to notify use by toast but it is for particular time also a problem is that how to attached it with edit text show i get solution of my question.