# How do I Customize EditText setError() popup view

Tags: android

I was working on 'setError' to show error messages.

My requirement is to change the red popup lines of `setError()` view to black and I'm trying to use `"android:errorMessageBackground"` in styles.xml which extends EditText widget. But unfortunately i'm getting "No Resource found error"

Using Theme : `Theme.NoTitleBar`
Used Base API: 2.2 (Even tried with 4.0.3 also)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218691/how-to-display-input-errors-in-popup this will helpful

Comment: do you have any sample regarding above

Comment: can i use <item name="android:errorMessageBackground"></item> for changing error popup view

Answer (score -1):

check edittext input data where you needed, if it is null then use `edittext.setError()` method to show error.

```
if( editText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
     editText.setError("Please enter Value");
```

And this code remove error from edittext, when you focus or click on edittext to enter data.

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText.setError(null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: and also pass `textView.setError(null);` to remove the error warning