# Change style of EditText.setError(String)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Is it possible to change the style of the "error popup" which can by shown with the `EditText.setError(String)` method? Or is this an unstylable popup :-/

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218691/how-to-display-input-errors-in-popup) might help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change the colour of the text using this method. Just use the html

UserNameEdt.setError(Html.fromHtml("please enter user name"));

Comment: I don't want to change the text color, but the background of the error popup. In my case, the red line breaks the color scheme in my app..