# How custom seterror() background and icon

Tags: android, validation, background, android-edittext

A lot of posts talk about this probleme, but nobody give the solution to custom the background of seterror() of EditText. It is really possible?

I have this :http://www.romito.fr/public/images/edittext-before.png

->And i would like that : http://www.romito.fr/public/images/edittext-after.png

I already tried all solutions found on stackoverflow... (like [How to display input errors in popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218691/how-to-display-input-errors-in-popup) for example)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your image on the edittext background in the XML code and then do this:

```
if(some error)
   YOUR_IMAGE.setVisibility(View.VISBILE);
else
   YOUR_IMAGE.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```