# Customise error text border android on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-theme, errortemplate

I want to create customize <kbd>errorText</kbd> of <kbd>EditText</kbd> with meaning full border.

```
editeText.setError(" ");
```

gives error message with red border which is good for showing it's required or validating field.

I've created customize error message with only icon difference in it.

Snipped used to change the icon of error message:-

```
    final Drawable error_indicator;
    error_indicator = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.error_icon_mdpi);
    int left = 0;
    int top = 0;
    int right = error_indicator.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int bottom = error_indicator.getIntrinsicWidth();
    error_indicator.setBounds(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom));
    addSxName.setError("Enter patient name in here", error_indicator);
```

Here its what it looked like.

[image: What i got]

What I'm looking for:-

[image: What I'm looking for]

But as a ToolTip or something that red border is little bit eye catcher.

Can we modify the modify of that errorBox?

Comment: you can create your drawable and then set to error Message, see this link to understand better, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218691/how-to-display-input-errors-in-popup

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan : Where you guiding I've created from that link only. But I'm looking to change the border around `error()` from red to green. Any suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: can you create one drawable with green border and set to your error message? did you test that?

Comment: you have to set border of edittext ?

Comment: @VikalpPatel did you solve this..i am lloking for same answer

Comment: @Johnson : I'vent implemented further on these. But you can achieve customize error box using custom pop up box/alert dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Its not possible**

**Alternate solution**

1. Dont use setError()
2. Create custom popup window
3. create your own set error method and show the popup window there