# I wish I could make setError view same as android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, uiview, custom-controls

**Hello Folks ,Recently I've worked with toast view for iOS ,Now I've been trying to make custom view like  ,I want to make that kind of UIView for iOS and would like to know if this is possible using iOS and How? Thanks any help will be appreciated.**

-- I want to achieve output in iOS like shown images 
 [image: Image1] [image: Image2]

**Can Any one help me out?**

Folks really Sorry for my bad english

Comment: If I've understood you correctly I think this is what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5232885/486604

Comment: Thanks @eth0 but I want to get that kinda output in iOS.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the iOS platform, how does it work? From your screenshots above I've gathered the red exclamation mark should always show if the field is empty, but the hint "Please enter password" should only should once the user has clicked on the password text box.

Comment: For which reason people down voted any ones question.. this is not a proper way

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to mimic the shown UI element in Android (which my answer is based on), although you want to do it the other way round. If you do a quick edit I will remove the downvote. It's still bad practice to mimic UI elements, no matter on what platform.

Comment: @vlad I just edited my question as you said. I really appreciate your answer :) (but its not for iOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably is possible, but really:

> Don't mimic UI elements from other platforms

From: [Pure Android](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

Edit:
Thought you wan't to mimic an iOS UI element in Android, but it's the other way round. In any case, mimicking UI elements from other platforms is bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer but my client want to have on iOS Platform and I don't have idea that How can I get following output    :)